# Add SOShipline row selected event

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to make the ShippedQty readonly based on a new status I created as a custom field in the SOShipment row.  I need to get the SOShipment record in the SOShipLine_RowSelected event, but the PXSelect keeps giving me an error.  Please see my code below:

```
    protected virtual void SOShipLine_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        SOShipLine soShipLine = (SOShipLine)e.Row;
        if (soShipLine != null)
        {
            SOShipment soShipment = PXSelect<SOShipment,
                        Where<SOShipment.shipmentNbr, Equal<Required<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>>>>.Select(this, soShipLine.ShipmentNbr);
            var soShipmentExt = PXCache<SOShipment>.GetExtension<SOShipmentExt>(soShipment);

            if (soShipment.Status == "N" && soShipmentExt.UsrEDIStatus != "N")
            {
                PXUIFieldAttribute.SetEnabled<SOShipLine.shippedQty>(sender, e.Row, Base.IsImport);
            }
        }
```

I am getting the error: CS0120  An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PXSelectBase.Select(params object[])'

Anyone have any idea why?  I have used this type of select many places.  I think it is having issue with the soShipLine.ShipmentNbr parameter in the Select.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "this" variable in your function is an instance of PXGraphExtension, not PXGraph. You can get the graph by passing "Base" (with capital B) to the Select function.

I would caution against selects in the RowSelected event since it can significantly decrease performance of the screen. In this case, you're trying to get information from the current shipment, which you could also retrieve from Base as well (`Base.Document.Current` variable).

Comment: I thought I should be able to get the shipment from the cache, but I tried to access it as:   SOShipment soShipment = (SOShipment)e.Row;  but it failed on execution.  How do I access it from base.  I have done a lot of custom coding adding this ASN module, but not a lot of extending existing graphs.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Also, do I need to include "base.SOShipLine_RowSelected(sender, e);" in the beginning of the extension?  The T300 documentation shows it, but I get an error trying to include it.  
Error CS0117 'PXGraphExtension<SOShipmentEntry>' does not contain a definition for 'SOShipLine_RowSelected'

Comment: e.Row will return you an instance of SOShipLine, not an SOShipment. You'll find it at Base.Document.Current. On your second question, This is not an override, so there's no point to invoke the base class function yourself.

Comment: Thanks again.  I changed the code as follows and it is working fine.  Awesome help.  
SOShipment soShipment = Base.Document.Search<SOShipment.shipmentNbr>(soShipLine.ShipmentNbr);